# VBA Excel 2007 - Cells.Find

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please explain how to read the below code to find last column and row with data?

```
Last_Column = Sheets("Combined").Cells.Find("", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
Last_Row = Sheets("Combined").Cells.Find("", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the *intersect* of the last used column and row you should adapt your code to

1. Search for `"*"` to match any wildcard not for `""` which is for blank cells *(NB: with this change your code above will work in a limited sense (see 2-3 below) if you run it from the `combined` sheet*
2. It is more robust not to assume the sheet has data, ie set ranges and then test they are `Not Nothing`
3. When using a starting cell ie `'[a1]` you should specify the sheet name as well to esnure the code works if you are running it from different sheets, ie `ws.[a1]` below

   ```
   Sub FindLast()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range
   Set ws = Sheets("combined")
   Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
   Set rng2 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
   If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "Last cell is " & Cells(rng1.Row, rng2.Column).Address(0, 0)
   Else
       MsgBox "No cells found"
   End If
   End Sub
   ```